# Birt report - not printing multiple reports on Maximo

Tags: birt, maximo

Birt report not printing multiple reports on Maximo, When I print one workorder it prints perfectly.

But when I select multiple workorders it just prints the first workorder from the selected list.  Can someone point me in the right direction as to what needs to be looked at?  is it the SQL statement or Birt Elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with looking at the rptdesign file and see if it handles multiple WO#'s in the data set query.